# Program hangs when running (??)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a macro for a login screen that I'm developing to make excel a "database", the following code is to check if any "text boxes" are empty, if the 2 "text boxes" are filled. , the macro will check if there is a user whose name and password are connected, but the program crashes when I run it, maybe due to the number of processes, is there a way to make this code a lighter code?

```
    Private Sub bt_seguinte_Click()

Dim c As Long, usuario_verify, senha_verify

usuario_verify = tb_usuario.Value
senha_verify = tb_senha.Value
lb_erro_usuario.Visible = False
lb_erro_senha.Visible = False

Select Case True
    
Case Trim(usuario_verify) = "" And Trim(senha_verify) = ""
    lb_erro_usuario.Visible = True
    lb_erro_senha.Visible = True
    
Case Trim(usuario_verify) = ""
    lb_erro_usuario.Visible = True
    
Case Trim(senha_verify) = ""
      lb_erro_senha.Visible = True

Case Else

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

contar_usuarios = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For c = 1 To contar_usuarios

    Sheets("Usuários").Cells(1, 4).Offset(c).Select
    
    Select Case True
    
    Case ActiveCell = usuario_verify
        Exit For
    
    Case ActiveCell = contar_usuarios And ActiveCell <> usuario_verify
        lb_erro_usuario.Visible = True
        lb_erro_usuario.Caption = "*Usuário não encontrado"
    
    Case ActiveCell <> usuario_verify
    End Select

Next c


If lb_erro_usuario.Caption <> "*Usuário não encontrado" Then

For c = 1 To contar_usuarios

    Sheets("Usuários").Cells(1, 5).Offset(c).Select
     
    Select Case True
    
    Case ActiveCell = senha_verify
        Exit For
    
    Case ActiveCell = contar_usuarios And ActiveCell <> senha_verify
        lb_erro_senha.Visible = True
        lb_erro_senha.Caption = "*Senha ou Nome de Usuário incorretos"
    
    Case ActiveCell <> senha_verify
    End Select
Next c

Else
End If
End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the code since I don't understand the language. I'll advice you to write as much as possible of your code in English, that way it will be easier to ask for help. How many users do you have? If it's not that many you will probably find it easier to hard code the credentials in the code.

Comment: When you debug (single step) through the code, on which line does it behave differently from what you have programmed (or from what you expect)?

Comment: I only have 2 users

Comment: believe it or not, when I debug in stages, everything goes the right way.

Comment: What do you mean with "debug in stages"? Is `bt_seguinte` in sheet `Usuários` or in a different sheet? How does the "program crashes" manifest? What happens that you call crash? Btw. Your program does not have "number of processes", there's no need to think about making it lighter. Please answer my questions, in the mean time I will try the program.

Comment: when I say crash, I say the program doesn't respond and the blue ball appears thinking

Comment: The button is contained in a Form

Comment: I don't know what I did, but it looks like the program stopped crashing, thanks everyone for the help :)

Comment: There is a serious problem in the logic. Your code accepts anybody's password since you traverse all passwords and accept any that match the input. Once you have found a user, you should of course only verify that users password with the entered one.

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The error I mentioned concerning any of the password being accepted for any one user is because in your code you traverse first through all user names until you find one, but then you start to search all passwords until you find one that fits the entered one. These two are not necessarily on the same row, meaning that any name in combination with any password is accepted.

To correct this, you must verify that the password beside the found name (on the same row) is same as the one entered.

Here is the `Select Case` block as I would do it. When you find the name, check if `(Cells(c, 5) = senha_verify)`. `c` is the row number and 5 is the column where passwords are stored. If both match set `name_found = True` and exit the for loop.

If the name only was a match, continue through the list as there might be other persons with the same name, but obviously with a different password.

```
Select Case True
    Case Trim(usuario_verify) = ""
        lb_erro_usuario.Visible = True
    Case Trim(senha_verify) = ""
        lb_erro_senha.Visible = True
    Case Else
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        contar_usuarios = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For c = 1 To contar_usuarios
            Sheets("Users").Cells(1, 4).Offset(c - 1).Select

            Select Case True
                Case ActiveCell = usuario_verify
                    If Cells(c, 5) = senha_verify Then
                        name_found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
        
                Case ActiveCell.Row = contar_usuarios And ActiveCell <> usuario_verify
                    lb_erro_usuario.Visible = True
                    lb_erro_usuario.Caption = "*Usuário não encontrado"
            End Select
        
        Next c

        If name_found Then
            lb_erro_usuario.Visible = True
            lb_erro_usuario.Caption = "*Usuário encontrado"
        Else
            lb_erro_senha.Visible = True
            lb_erro_senha.Caption = "*Senha ou Nome de Usuário incorretos"
        End If

End Select
```

Note that I added a variable

```
    Dim name_found As Boolean
```